# Capacitor + Nuxt 3 hot reload problem: Waiting for connectivity with npm

Tags: capacitor, nuxtjs3

I'm developing an app with Capacitor + Nuxt 3, everything works very well, it's a pretty cool environment, the only problem is hot reload doesn't work.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "ionic:build": "npm run build",
    "ionic:serve": "npm run dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n-edge": "^8.0.0-beta.12-28122654.89ddb67",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.6.6",
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.2.0",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
    "nuxt-icon": "^0.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.62.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-firebase/authentication": "^5.1.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@capgo/capacitor-purchases": "5.0.8",
    "@egoist/tailwindcss-icons": "^1.0.7",
    "@iconify/json": "^2.2.54",
    "@morev/vue-transitions": "^2.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/color-mode": "^3.3.0",
    "firebase": "9.23.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.7.0",
    "maz-ui": "^3.9.0",
    "nuxt-icons": "^3.2.1",
    "nuxt-snackbar": "^1.0.3",
    "nuxt-vuefire": "^0.1.6",
    "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.3.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0",
    "vuefire": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "overrides": {
    "vue": "latest"
  },
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "@nuxt/kit": "$nuxt",
      "@nuxt/schema": "$nuxt"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the command:

```
npx ionic cap run android --target=aba5e7d2  --livereload --external
```

I get an infinite list of this message:

> [INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...

and it doesn't start. Any idea?